# Create a column with calendar date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet in Excel, what I want is, to create a column, where each row starts with a specific date, for example, "3 april 2017". Then, when I drag and scroll bottom I want it to increase by one day.

So, basically, I want to create a sheet where each row starts with a specific date, where the first date is equal to now date, and next row is today date + 1 day.

I'm not very keen in Excel and I tried `=WEEKDAY` and `=DAY`formulas, but I could not get what I want.

Is there any formula I can use to easily achieve this task?

Comment: Dates are stored as numbers, so just `=A1+1` will work

Comment: @CallumDA could you provide an example please?

Comment: So if you put `=TODAY()` in cell `A1` and then in `A2` put `=A1+1`. Make sure both cells are formatted as `Date` and you should get the result you're after. You can drag that formula down.

Comment: @CallumDA how could i format cell as date and set specific date string output, like "3 april 2017" ?

Comment: Select your cells, right click > format cells > custom and then type in `d mmmm yyyy`

Comment: @CallumDA problem solved, thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, Excel stores dates as numbers so to add a day to a date you simply need to add one to it:

```
=A1+1
```

... for example, when the original date is in cell `A1`.

To format this as you require, use the following *custom format* string:

```
d mmmm yyyy
```